# Flutter FutureBuilder not reloading after add new record

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a customer crud with listview page populated with futurebuilder that loads customer data from database and another page to insert/edit new customers.

I want to reload the listview after insert or edit a customer and go back to listview page by tapping back button.

I've tried RouteObserver didPop and didPopNext but without success.

[Listview page code](https://github.com/dibmartins/flutter/blob/master/lib/modules/clientes/widgets/Listar.dart)

[Edit page code](https://github.com/dibmartins/flutter/blob/master/lib/modules/clientes/widgets/Editar.dart)

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the other page with `Navigator` you can await the result and do whatever you want with it.

```
Cliente clienteEditado = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<Cliente>(builder: (context) => Editar(cliente: clientes[index])));
clientes[index] = clienteEditado;
setState(() {});
```

To receive the cliente above you do the following in the editing page:

```
onPressed: () {
 _save();
 Navigator.pop(context, widget.cliente);
}
```

Comment: I think, it has to be `Cliente clienteEditado = await Navigator.push...`

Comment: Yes, completely right. Forgot it in the copy and paste. Otherwise it has no sense because you only have the clienteEditado when coming back from the second page.